# Link to next post

Tags: hugo

My structure in `content`:

```
content
|-post
| |-00.md
| |-01.md
| |-02.md
|-about.md
```

---

In the single template for the posts I want to have a footer that:

- is a link to the next post or, if no next post is available
- is the text "to be continued".

In Pseudo-template-code that means:

```
{{ if nextpost.exists }} #. becomes nexpost here
  <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
{{ end }}
```

Where `nextpost` is currentpost+1

---

How to create that kind of link?

Answer (score 20):

It sounds like you want the [.NextInSection](https://gohugo.io/variables/page/) variable. If you use the [with](https://gohugo.io/templates/go-templates/#conditionals) function, you can make it work like you want to.

```
{{ with .NextInSection }}
  <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
{{ end }}
```

You can use `.PrevInSection` in a similar way also.